# How to display messagebox for Custom Validator error message?

Tags: asp.net, validation, messagebox, validation-controls

In my user control i am having the code as:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvOrgTypeGrid" runat="server" Enabled="false" Display="Dynamic" 
            ErrorMessage="Please add rules to get eligible members" >
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

In Code behind, I am having a function as:

```
    public void Validate(bool isOrgType)
    {
        if (!isOrgType) return;
        if (Rules.Any()) return;
        cvOrgTypeGrid.Enabled = true;
        cvOrgTypeGrid.IsValid = false;
    }
```

I would like to get the error message "Please add rules to get eligible members" in messagebox.

Anybody please help out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Validation Summary Control, check this msdn [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd5c6s6h%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I have tried it.. Its not working.. Its actually working for RequiredFieldValidator but its not working here. Is there any problem because of updatepanel?

Comment: mmm, can you try putting the Validation Summary Control inside the update panel? I am not sure if it will work